# shortcodes not working [dt_carousel & [dt_fancy_image

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I've been asked to investigate an issue with a WordPress site that's displaying shortcodes. The site is new to me and I don't know who built it. The shortcodes start with `[dt_carousel ...` or `[dt_fancy_image ...`. I'm trying to find out which plugin would use this shortcode so I can reinstall it, or if it's already installed contact the author or fix it in some other way. A Google search just brings up other websites that are displaying the shortcodes and there are many of these, so it's common problem without an easy-to-find solution. I've tried disabling plugins to see if there's a clash somewhere, but I still get the shortcode displaying. The site is using the theme Sinatra and the WPBakery page builder. So any help to point me in the right direction to get the shortcodes working this will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell they appear to belong to themes developed by these guys: https://themeforest.net/user/dream-theme, particularly "The7". You will need to check with them if it's possible to make the shortcodes work in another theme.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for your comment, I think you maybe right. There are a couple of "The7" plugins on the site that are missing licences and need updating. Once my client has purchased the licences and I've conpleted the updates, I'll confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is less complicated than you expect. The wrong theme had been activated. Activating the theme 'The7' solved the issue. There are loads of sites out there with the same issue, hopefully this may help those who manage them.